# eclipse search - regex finding start/end of file with carriage return

Tags: regex, eclipse, search

I would like to remove any line breaks/carriage returns at the start and end of files but eclipse doesn't seem to recognize `$$` or `^^` for end/start of file. Anyone know how to do a regex with eclipse search?

---

```
sof ^^ Start of File
eof $$ End of File
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems by default, the multi-line flag `m` is enabled in Eclipse, causing `^` and `$` to match start- and end-of-lines. You can disable the `m` flag by adding `(?-m)` in front of your regex.

I just tested it, and it only removes line breaks at the start or end of the file:

```
(?-m)(^\s+|\s+$)
```

Comment: @Mike, yeah, you're right, Eclipse does things a bit different than I thought. I just did a test, it does work now.

Comment: I just tried this with \?>(\s)+$ and (?-m)\?>(\s)+$, and the formed did find a stray ?>\n in the middle of the file, while the latter only found those at the end of the file.

But why is disabling multiline flag causing it to... find EOF (seems multiline?)

Comment: @Spork, better create a question of your own, instead of using these small comment boxes for Q&A. Good luck!

Answer (score 16):

You can use `\A` to represent the start of the file, and `\Z` to represent the end of the file.

Comment: They won't match on their own. `\A.` will find the first character of the file though.

Comment: `\A.` seems to work not in every case. It shows me the start of a text block in a test, however.

Comment: \Adescribe is working well in Rubymine for finding items that begin with the word describe only at the top of the file.  Thanks!

Comment: unrelated to eclipse but works on **netbeans** in current file

Comment: If you want to do a search and replace, use `\A.` as the pattern and replace with `new text\R\0`.  This way it puts the one character that matched into the replacement text.